# Python seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I'm doing a heatmap. I have a list of list in this format

[ **[x1,y1,value1] , [x2,y2,value2]...**  ]

I have done a Dataframe like following:

```
           X         Y   VEL
0  -4.799990  1.599996   93.294099
1  11.199978 -1.599996   97.714788
2 -14.399973 -1.599996  131.289188
3   4.799990  4.799995  118.418184
4   4.799988 -4.799995   91.098021
5  -4.799988 -1.599996   91.177642
6  -1.599996  4.799989   85.077989
7   4.799989  1.600002   67.702695
8   1.599995 -1.600002  110.756954
9  -1.599995 -4.799989  112.697441
```

I want to put in 2D axis with seaborn putting on them *vel*

I have this code.
list is in the format that I have told before.
pd is pandas library
sb is seaborn library

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=["X", "Y", "VELOCIDAD"])

    df = df.head(10)
    print(df)
    data_extract = pd.pivot_table(df, values='VELOCIDAD',
                                  index='X',
                                  columns='Y')

    plt.show(sb.heatmap(data_extract,cmap="YlGnBu"))
```

I get the following graphic:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrZjI.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only have 10 values, a heatmap seems a bit strange. Maybe a scatterplot? `sns.scatterplot('X', 'Y', hue='VEL', data=df)`. Please don't write `plt.show(sb.heatmap(...))`, as that doesn't make sense for matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want 'Vel' values to be put on them try :
`plt.show(sb.heatmap(data_extract,cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True))`